# unable to use two way Binding with my control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, slider

I am new to `binding`. I have binded `slider` value to my control's property and my controls property get changed when I change the slider value.
Now, when I need to change the slider value by changing my property value, it does not work..

I modified the `xaml` from some internet source, but still not get the expected output.
 can anyone help me out...

```
<Grid>
    <cc:MyControl Name="mycntrl" ZoomPercentage="{Binding  ElementName=slider,Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></cc:MyControl>
    <Slider Name="slider"  Margin="20,20,20,400" Minimum="100" Maximum="400"></Slider>
</Grid>
```

**Updated:**

My code behind for my ZoomPercentage dependency property is below

```
public double ZoomPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(ZoomPercentageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ZoomPercentageProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

My dependency registration

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomPercentageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomPercentage", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ZoomPercentagePropertyChanged));


public static void ZoomPercentagePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.OldValue != null)
        {
            if ((double)args.NewValue != (double)args.OldValue)
            {
                MyControl mycontrol = obj as MyControl;
                mycontrol .ZoomTo((int)((double)args.NewValue));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ZoomPercentage` property  should  be implemented as a [**`Dependencyproperty`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Something like this

```
public class MyControl:UserControl 
{
  public MyControl() : base() { }
  public double ZoomPercentage
  {
    get { return (double)this.GetValue(ZoomPercentageProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ZoomPercentageProperty, value); } 
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomPercentageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ZoomPercentage", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl:),new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a data bound control in the UI to update after changes made in code then you have to do one of two things. One option is to correctly implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in the class that you declared your `Value` property.

The other is to declare your `Value` property as a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), although you should only really do this in the code behind of your `Window` or `UserControl` and opt for the first method if you are using a view model. The purpose of these two methods is for you to 'plug in' to WPF notification framework, so that your UI control will update. Please read the linked pages for more information.